# Output of Oscillator and Modulator is Absent

Tags: modulation, proteus

I am designing circuit of AM transmitter. This circuit I got from youtube. You can have it from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3I_e7gIyfQg&list=PLptvBCLYNDi3gOY1P_PSSIkyuiTu1a1EI&index=28)
[image]

I designed the same  circuit in proteus and simulate it and try to obtain different waveforms on Oscilloscope. I got input wave of mp3 player but there is no high frequency carrier wave(Oscillator generated wave) and modulated wave.[image]

I am beginner in proteus so its bit difficult to understand the problem.

Comment: Connect scope input C to U1:A pin 1 (not the end of the pot) and see if your carrier oscillator is working. Capital P for Proteus. (Capitals matter.)

Comment: I connected the scope to U1:A 1 pin but still there is no output of oscillator.@Transistor

Comment: I was going to respond, explaining what is going on in this circuit, but without component designators in the schematic that would be too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Figure 1. With a 9 V single-ended supply you are operating below the recommended minimum of 10 V.*

Try swapping the opamps with a newer low-voltage type.

Get the oscillator working and the rest should work.

Comment: But component TL072 is not available with lower rating and the available component of Op-amp doesn't have voltage rating. @Transistor